# How to remove gaps between bars in a bar chart

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

I'm making a bar chart in Matplotlib with a call like this:

```
xs.bar(bar_lefts, bar_heights, facecolor='black', edgecolor='black')
```

I get a barchart that looks like this:

[image: Bar chart with gaps]

What I'd like is one with no white gap between consecutive bars, e.g. more like this:

[image]

Is there a way to achieve this in Matplotlib using the `bar()` function?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Add `width=1.0` as a keyword argument to `bar()`.  E.g.

`xs.bar(bar_lefts, bar_heights, width=1.0, facecolor='black', edgecolor='black')`.

This will fill the bars gaps vertically.

Comment: `width=?`.  The snippet above breaks as width isn't being given as a keyword argument but rather as a variable (which doesn't exist).

Comment: @Bryce Thomas:If you just write width ,it takes as width=1 I think (to me it works).So,with width=1 ,does it work as you wanted?

Comment: Fair enough, I'm surprised it works at all on your end.  On my system it's (almost) a syntax error, as the language is interpreting width to be a non-named parameter, and it can't find any variable named width in my program obviously.  Yep, width=1 seems to do what I wanted.

Comment: Setting `linewidth=0.0` and `width=1.0` will remove the bar edge line. This has removed the (visually appearing grey) space between bars in my case of 10000+ data points.

Answer (score 7):

It has been 8 years since this question was asked, and the matplotlib API now has built-in ways to produce filled, gapless bars: `pyplot.step()` and `pyplot.stairs()` with the argument `fill=True`.

See [the docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/stairs_demo.html) for a fuller comparison, but the primary difference is that `step()` defines the step positions with N `x` and N `y` values just like `plot()` would, while `stairs()` defines the step positions with N heights and N+1 edges, like what `hist()` returns. It is a subtle difference, and I think both tools can create the same outputs.

Comment: Thanks. Bar can work but it leaves some barely visible gaps in the saved pdf even with bar width set to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Just set the width 1 over the number of bars, so:

```
width = 1 / len(bar_lefts)
xs.bar(bar_lefts, bar_heights, width=width, color='black')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the width equal to the distance between two bars:

```
width = bar_lefts[-1] - bar_lefts[-2]
xs.bar(bar_lefts, bar_heights, width=width)
```